# How to add tooltips to SharePoint 2013 form fields

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, visual-studio-2012, jquery-ui

I am working with a User (sandbox) Solution created in Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint 2013. I have been asked to add custom tooltips to the default new and edit form fields.  I have not been able to locate any information on this after searching for days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When the page goes to edit mode you can load the http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ as dotsa suggested

And then you should be able to attach the tooltip using the class or any selector
say

```
$( document ).tooltip();
```

Make sure that the fields you want tooltip are added with **title** attribute

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify add/new/edit forms of the list or document library you are working with.

Then you can use any of the numerous tooltip js libraries i.e.  http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ to add tooltips to your form.

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert!  I am trying to edit the new/edit forms using JSLink and I am not having any luck.

Comment: I am able to get CSR working with regular input textboxes, but it gets very difficulty when attempting to render the SharePoint 2013 InputFormTextBox control using JSLink.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the EditForm or NewForm in SharePoint Designer, and add an html select element. Each option value will correspond to a field name or id, and the option title will contain the corresponding field tooltip. You will have to use jQuery to update your fields (input) title. Kindly see this post http://sharepointhowtwo.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-add-tooltip-to-sharepoint-choice_27.html.

Regards